# Mac OS X cron log / tracking

Tags: macos, cron

What is the best way to determine if a cron job has run? Is there a log? What techniques do people use?

Answer (score 13):

With macos Monterey it seems you should use the following shell command

```
log show --process cron
```

you can add --info and/or --debug if required

Comment: I get the folloring error. Any suggestion? `log: unrecognized option '--process'`

Comment: See man log:
...     log show [--archive archive | --file file] [--predicate filter] [--process pid | process] [--source]
         [--style default | compact | json | ndjson | syslog] [--color auto | always | none]
         [--start date/time] [--end date/time] [--[no-]info] [--[no-]debug] [--[no-]pager] [--[no-]signpost]
         [--last time [m|h|d]] [--timezone local | timezone]
...

Comment: I checked the man page and it doesn't show the process flag for the show command unfortunately. Hence why I asked for suggestions.  `log show [--archive archive | --file file] [--predicate filter]          [--source] [--style default | compact | json | syslog]          [--color auto | always | none] [--start date/time] [--end date/time]          [--[no-]info] [--[no-]debug] [--[no-]signpost] [--last time [m|h|d]]          [--timezone local | timezone]`

Comment: It seems not working on my device which is running macOS Ventura 13.4.

Answer (score 3):

I just redirected the output of the cron script >> to a file and that seemed to work well enough.

Comment: Mind adding a quick example of what you mean by that?

Comment: This will run the script and output its stdout/err to the logfile: `* * * * * /usr/local/bin/script >>/var/log/script.log 2>&1`. You can use `logrotate` to clean up the log to make sure it doesn't fill your disk.

Comment: If you don't want to learn/use `logrotate` you can also use this trick I tried documenting here: https://gist.github.com/mnadel/a14804e23533f43e91818a706c2fb7d4

Answer (score 1):

Cron on mac automatically logs user's jobs into

```bash
/var/mail/{username}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
tail -f /var/log/syslog | grep CRON
```

It can happen that "syslog" is not located in "/var/log/", in this case just run the following line to get its location:

```
whereis syslog
```

Comment: that didn't work even with the correct syslog absolute path.