# Issue With Cron Job On MAC OS

Tags: php, cron

I'm trying to run my first cron job on MAC OS (my localhost is running MAMP).

To access crontab, to run a cron job, I'm typing the following into the command line:

```
crontab -e
```

Then I press `i` on the keyboard to go into insert mode to insert the cron job.

The cron job inserted is

```
*   *   *   *   *   wget http://localhost:8888/project/cron.php
```

Then I press `esc` and type `:wq` in the command line.

I then get a message:

```
installing new crontab
```

Then I check what cronjobs are running with `crontab -l` and it says:

```
*   *   *   *   *   wget http://localhost:8888/project/cron.php
```

But nothing happens...

On a separate note, below is the script I'm executing as a test script in the cron.php file. It is meant to generate a new time stamp in a text file in the root of the project (the cron job is supposed to make this happen every minute):

```
<?php
$file = dirname(__FILE__) . '/output.txt';

$data = "hello, it's " . date('d/m/Y H:i:s') . "\n";

file_put_contents($file, $data, FILE_APPEND);

?>
```

If anyone has any advice as to why this isn't working I'd be hugely grateful.

I've tried the steps shown above at both system level (i.e macmini) and also in my 'project' folder.

I'm completely new to all of this so any help would be amazing.

Comment: Have you [checked the logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5475800/mac-os-x-cron-log-tracking)? Does running `wget http://localhost:8888/project/cron.php` yourself in the terminal work as expected? Sometimes the cron environment runs with different paths configured. It's always best to use full paths, eg `/usr/local/bin/wget http://localhost:8888/project/cron.php` (type `which wget` to find the full path)

Comment: FYI, you don't need to call your PHP via `wget`. It's often simpler to directly execute the PHP script, eg `* * * * * /path/to/php /path/to/project/cron.php`

Comment: Hi @Phil this worked - i did `*   *   *   *   *  /usr/bin/php  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/cron.php` if you want to do that as an answer i'll mark it as correct.

Comment: Hmm, would be best to find out why your original approach didn't work before adding random answers that _might_ work

Comment: What of these things runs as which user? Permissions and ownership of files matter!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this was to use the file paths not the url. First I found where the php was located. I did this with:

```
whereis php
```

This gave me the following file path:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

I then got the FULL file path to the cron.php file in my project:

```
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/cron.php
```

I then combined the two in the crontab cron job:

```
*   *   *   *   *  /usr/bin/php  /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/project/cron.php
```

The actual steps I used are the same as in my original question.

Comment: Your original problem may have been the path to `wget`. Would be good if you could try that out too

Comment: @Phil the `wget` url to the file was what was given in the question. I even echoed some text out in that file to double check it. Unless I'm misunderstanding your point?

Comment: I meant use `which wget` to get the path to the executable and use that in your crontab, eg `/usr/local/bin/wget http://localhost...`. FYI, I think using the PHP executable is the better option but would just like to know why your original solution didn't work

Comment: @Phil actually did try that but I got (and still get) a message that says `wget not found` hence then trying the file path.

Comment: That's the first you've mentioned of any error messages which would be good to include in your question. FYI, I just made up `/usr/local/bin/wget`, that might not be correct. What do you get from `which wget` or `whereis wget`?